# Why is maven looking for `webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml` instead of `web-app\WEB-INF\web.xml`

Tags: java, grails, maven, web-applications

I have a Maven/Grails app that almost builds, but fails to find `web.xml` at `[my-app]\webapp\WEB-INF\web.xml`. But the directory structure contains a `web-app` folder, as usual, not `webapp`.

Is this a matter of an old version of maven interacting with Grails in a strange way? Or is it a bad error message? Or any other ideas?

Comment: a few questions... if you didn't create the project using the maven grails archetype how did you create it and can you post the pom? are you getting the error when you're running mvn grails:run-app or another command?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?  If not I would guess that you could fix this by brute force just by creating a new maven/grails project using the archetype and copying the app-specific grails-app/web-app contents into the directory structure that gets created by the archetype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard for maven is to name the directory "webapp" not "web-app"

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Hmm, I updated this answer on Friday, but upon closer reflection it doesn't seem to address the actual issue. Grails apps never follow this structure, and never have a webapp inside src.